# Given $g$ find an $f$ which is solution for $L f = g$. How do I do this?

Tags: analysis, reference-request, differential-operators, inverse-problems

I am learning about Stochastic processes.
To characterize uniqueness of solutions to a given Stochastic differential equation, I need to find for each continuous function $g :\Bbb{R}^2_+ \to \Bbb{R}$ a function $f:\Bbb{R}^2_+ \to \Bbb{R}$ such that

$$ -\gamma f + (\partial_x f) (y-x) + (\partial_y f) (x-y) + \frac{1}{2} \bigg((\partial_{xx} f) x + (\partial_{yy} f) y\bigg) = g $$

This is I believe an inverse problem which has to do with spectral techniques such as proving that $\gamma  \in \rho(L)$ where

$$L f = (\partial_x f) (y-x) + (\partial_y f) (x-y) + \frac{1}{2} \bigg((\partial_{xx} f) x + (\partial_{yy} f) y\bigg)$$

Maybe this can be solved more straightforwardly by finding a Green's function $G(x,y,\tilde{x}, \tilde{y})$ that satisfies 
$$ -\gamma G  - L G = \delta_{x -\tilde{x}} \delta_{y - \tilde{y}}$$

or something similar and then defining

$$f = G*g. $$

**How can we find such an $f$? Does it exist? Is there any good reference on the literature for this subject?**

---

Note: Here $(\partial_x f) (y-x) $ means $(\partial_x f(x,y)) \cdot (y-x)$

Comment: What do you mean by $fx$ and $fy$ in your notation? And is $\gamma$ fixed or not?

Comment: @demitau, I edited the question, is it clearer? we are multipling the functions $f$ and $x$. $\gamma$ is positive and fixed.

Comment: Not completely. You are multyplying $f$ by $x$ after the differentiation (so you have $x\cdot \partial_{xx} f$) or before ($\partial_{xx}(f\cdot x)$)?

Comment: Ohh yes, you are right, it was quite confusing. we differentiate first and then multiply the functions.  so we have $x \cdot \partial_{xx} f$ I edited it again. Maybe now it's better.

Comment: It looks a bit like a trial-and-error exercise. Did you try to guess $f$ directly?

Comment: I find it very hard to guess. even for smooth functions. For instance, imagine your $g$ is a function with compact support $C^\infty$. can you guess what  is $f$? In fact I'm now trying to show that $\text{Range}(\gamma - L)$ is dense in $C^\infty_c$ which might be easier...

Comment: I mean, maybe if you consider $f=gw$, just put it in the equation and solve for $w$ it would help. For example I have tried it now and I got that one may start solving a simpler equation $xw_{xx}+yw_{yy} + (y-x)w_x + (x-y) w_y - \gamma w = 1$, where you don't have $g$.

Comment: My comments apply if you really need to find (as you stated) the function $f$. If you only need to prove its existence it's a different story.

Comment: To find the function is the best, but I'll be quite happy to know that such a function exists.

Comment: @demitau How did you find the simpler equation? $xw_{xx}+yw_{yy} + (y-x)w_x + (x-y) w_y - \gamma w = 1$. I am having trouble with the terms $g_x w, g_y w, g_{xx} w, g_{yy} w$ How did you simplified you equation?

Comment: They don't dissapear. You have a multiplier $g$ in front of experssion that I have written (if I did not make a mistake in computations). So one might hope that if $w$ solves my equation (which I don't know how to deal with, maybe some Fourier tricks), other terms (not having pure $g$ as multiplier) disappear automatically. So my comment was not very deep.