# a good book to study the theory of Finite ellement methods

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

I am dealing with elliptic PDE with dirichlet boundary condition,

In consequence of that, I started looking for a book that deals with Finite ellements method (FEM)

I am interested in a book oriented for mathematitians.

Do you suggest any?

Comment: Have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48579/any-great-introductory-books-for-finite-element-difference-methods?rq=1

Comment: If you must ask this question, please give the results of your search so far.  Cogent replies will certainly depend on what your own efforts achieved and on what mathematical background is supposed by various authors.

Comment: I don't know if that will help. I've read the wikipedia on FEM, and furthermore I looked up for some books on the reference list of the site, Many of the result are fit to engineers and related courses. I am interested in the theory for 2 dimensions, At the moment I am dealing with the following PDE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1449599/given-g-find-an-f-which-is-solution-for-l-f-g-how-do-i-do-this